# decompile an app binary to get back to source code

Tags: iphone, binary, decompiler

Is there anyway to take a binary - even signed by yourself, and get back to the code? I'm trying to recover something that I deleted a while ago... but have the binary here.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can disassemble a binary and get back assembly source, but there is no way to get back your original Objective-C structured source code.

---

**EDIT:**
You may want to give [Hopper](http://hopperapp.com/) a try. I didn't try it personally yet but [Mike Ash says it's good](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-01-06-the-hopper-disassembler.html).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [Hex-Rays decompiler](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/index.shtml). You need to have IDA Pro debugger to use it.