# Is it possible to view an iphones application source code?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [decompile an app binary to get back to source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661722/decompile-an-app-binary-to-get-back-to-source-code)
>   [Decompiling iOS Objective-C binaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475875/decompiling-ios-objective-c-binaries)

Some months ago i developed and iOS application. Recently i discovered a program called "ifunbox" which through it , i can have access to my application's .nib files , icons etc. I don't own a mac at the moment , so i can't really see if i can open the files with XCode and actually see my code. So is it possible that someone can download through "ifunbox" the .nib files and see my source code , or they are compiled so there is not such an issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code is compiled. Decompilers do exist, but their output is not particularly useful. I wouldn't be concerned about it if I were you.

Art assets, and some aspects of interface files will be accessible to other people who want to drill into your compiled app package, but your code is just as secure as any other closed source executable compiled from C (or it's variants like ObjC).

Answer (score 3):

No, your source code is not retrievable, because your released app is made by compiling the source code into an executable -- it's not the source code any more -- and then the executable binary is encrypted. However, some resources such as images can be pulled from your device once the app is installed.

See also [Decompiling iOS Objective-C binaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475875/decompiling-ios-objective-c-binaries)