# How to decompile framework file in iOS to get source code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, decompiler

I want to know is there any way/tools to decompile framework file in objective C to get the source code. Just like in java there are JAD and other tools to decompile byte code to source code.

Comment: This is not really possible, the compiled code is assembler code and you can't really get the original code back. Java (and .NET) are using a intermediate code which contains much of the original source code and therefor you can decompile it.

Answer (score 7):

You can disassemble a binary and get back assembly source, but there is no way to get back your original Objective-C structured source code.
You may want to give [Hopper](http://hopperapp.com/) a try. I didn't try it personally yet but [Mike Ash say](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-01-06-the-hopper-disassembler.html)s it's good.
Helper Source:- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661722/decompile-an-app-binary-to-get-back-to-source-code)