# iOS : How to generate a .framework file from a GitHub project

Tags: ios, cocoapods, carthage

There is a Swift project on GitHub that I want to include in my iOS app.

In my iOS app, I use Carthage. But the GitHub project is not compatible with Carthage (only with Cocoapods), so I need to include the .framework file in my project manually.

How can I generate the .framework file without Carthage?

Answer (score 0):

Building the framework is not always the same across projects. That being said, there should be a target available when you open the project to make the framework build. It should look something like this.

[image]

After clicking run the framework is usually output to the products directory.

[image]

If this doesn't work for you with this project then maybe you could share a link to the github page for the project and I could provide more instruction.

Comment: what if you only have a .framework and no .xcodeproj?

Comment: Not sure I know what you mean @SRMR. If you already have the .framework then you already have the code and you can include it in your project by dragging it in to Xcode. The .framework file is actually a directory that contains all of the compiled code of an external library.

Comment: Sure, let me try from a different angle: If I sent you a .framework by itself (where scheme might or might not have been shared), would you be able to turn that into a library or framework you could build on your own and share a scheme for?

Comment: The .framework contains the source code compiled into binary so its not possible to rebuild the framework into swift/objc code very easily. I don't think it would be possible to edit the scheme for a particular framework unless you were able to convert it back into that swift/objc source code. You can see this question for more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35061626/how-to-decompile-framework-file-in-ios-to-get-source-code).

Comment: That makes sense now, thanks for explaining all of that to me!

Answer (score 0):

1. Fork Project
2. Change scheme to `shared` in scheme management ([more information on Carthage docs](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#supporting-carthage-for-your-framework))
3. Add your fork to your `Cartfile`

You can stop here but I highly recommend do this after:

4. Update `README` with information about Carthage support
5. Make a pull request